# Chain CSS animations with infinite loop

Tags: css, css-animations

Is it possible to chain two animations and then loop this chain indefinitely?
`{|--ani1--|--ani1--|--ani1--|--ani2--|--ani2--|} x loop`

```
div {
    width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 3px solid black;
    animation: ani1 3s 0s 3, ani2 3s 9s 2;
    /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
}
@keyframes ani1 {
    from { background: green; }
    50% { background: red; }
    to { background: green; }    
}
@keyframes ani2 {
    from { width: 100px; }
    50% { width: 150px; }
    to { width: 100px; }    
}
```

tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/kQA6D/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, **no** (some work arounds are possible)

What your line `animation-count: infinte` is currently doing is this for the element: `animation: ani1 3s 0s infinite, ani2 3s 9s infinite;`. So, since the first animation declared has an iteration count of `infinite`, the second will never be reached

The easiest and most conventional way would be to use javascript and `animationEnd` to do so (I use Craig Buckler's [PrefixedEvent function](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) but it's not necessary)

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0],
    pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];    
function PrefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}    
PrefixedEvent(elem, "animationend", function() { switchAnims(elem) });    
function switchAnims(element) {
    if(element.style.animationName = "ani1") {
        element.style.animationName = "ani2";
    } else {
        element.style.animationName = "ani1";
    }
}
```

[image: jsFiddle] (webkit only - other prefixes need to be added)

Otherwise for a pure CSS fix at the moment you would have to combine them as one animation. For you that would look like

```
@keyframes aniBoth {
    0%, 16.666%, 33.333%     { background: green; }
    8.333%, 24.999%, 41.666% { background: red; }
    50%                      { background: green; }
    50.001%                  { background:white; width: 100px; }
    75%, 100%                { width: 100px; }
    62.5%, 87.5%             { width: 150px; }
}
```

[image: jsFiddle] (webkit only - other prefixes need to be added)

Comment: The pure CSS fix's syntax is confusing at first glance, but much more elegant and succinct than my solution. Kudos.

Comment: I did want it to be pure CSS, but the problem is
1) I will have to recalculate the percentages, 2) timing functions.

I guess I am left with javascript.

Answer (score 4):

No, you will need to declare it all in one animation with the specific steps you want, like so:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    animation: ani1 3s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes ani1 {
    0 { background: green; }
    10% { background: red; }
    20% { background: green; }
    30% { background: red; }
    40% { background: green; }
    50% { background: red; }
    60% { background: green; width: 50px; }
    70% { width: 100px; }
    80% { width: 150px; }
    90% { width: 100px; } 
    100% { width: 150px; }   
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/kQA6D/4/) (Uses `-webkit-` prefix to be viewable in Chrome)

Alternatively, you could declare your animations separately with a built in gap so that the two animations don't overlap, like so:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    animation: ani1 12s 0s infinite, ani2 12s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes ani1 {
    0%, 60%, 100% { background: white; }
    20%, 40% { background: green; }
    10%, 30%, 50% { background: red; }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
    60%, 80%, 100% { width: 100px; }
    70%, 90% { width: 150px; } 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/FLTbk/) (Uses `-webkit-` prefix to be viewable in Chrome)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Build the gap in the animations. In your example, you have it all in one animation, where the second animation starts at 50%. My method just starts the second animation at 60% and the first animation finishes by 60%, keeping them as separate keyframes, but preventing them from overlapping.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Here is a simplified example using the shorter syntax like yours: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/FLTbk/

Comment: Ah, I see! Silly of me to miss that

Comment: The problem when doing it in one animation (or with gaps) is that 1) I will have to recalculate the percentages, 2) timing functions.

Comment: @Qwerty Yeah, unfortunately I think Javascript is the only option here! Zach's solution should be what you need :-)